# Why doesn't the dirtyCOW PoC work on my VM?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, exploit

I've wanted to write an article about the DirtyCOW exploit. And I can't figure out why it's not working on my system.

I have a virtual machine from VirtualBox which is running Ubuntu 9.10 (which I've downloaded from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)), with the kernel version 2.6.31-14-generic. (which according to wikipedia is still vulnerable)

I've compiled the PoC that can be found [here](https://github.com/dirtycow/dirtycow.github.io/blob/master/dirtyc0w.c), and I run the following:

```
cow@dirtycow:~/Desktop$ uname -r
2.6.31-14-generic
cow@dirtycow:~/Desktop$ sudo su
[sudo] password for cow:
root@dirtycow:/home/cow/Desktop# echo "hey" > weird_file
root@dirtycow:/home/cow/Desktop# exit
exit
cow@dirtycow:~/Desktop$ ./dirtyc0w weird_file AA
mmap b77f2000

procselfmem -100000000

madvise 0

cow@dirtycow:~/Desktop$ cat weird_file
hey
```

I am using Oracle's VirtualBox to run the Ubuntu 9.10 vm, and the stats for the virtual machine are:

- 64 bit
- 3GB RAM Memory with 55GB HDD
- 3 CPUs (100% execution cap)

Comment: Output `procselfmem -100000000` most likely means, that every `write` call is **failed** (returns `-1`). The code does a **minimum checks**, so we could only guess why it behaves so. It could be that even `open()` call for file `/proc/self/mem` has been failed. You may try to debug the code (run via `gdb`, or insert `printf` calls). On Stack Overflow we expect the asker to perform some debugging.

Comment: I checked, the open call has been successful, and the other parameters are also OK.

Comment: So, which exact file operation is failed first?

Comment: It fails at the write and says Invalid Arguments, although the open is successful and the other parameters contain what they should